# Method in Policies does not return button for user of type Administrator

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble displaying the `Show` in `dojo.blade.php` button only for admins (role === 1) in my `showAdmin()` in the `UserPolicies.php` file, even though it's a admin type user the button is not visible to me.

- `UserPolicies.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function showAdmin(User $user){
        return $user->role === 1;
    }
}
```

- `DojoController.php`

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $dojo = DojoModel::find($id);
        $this->authorize('showAdmin', Auth::user());
        $fighter = FighterModel::get(['id','name']);
        $master = MasterModel::get(['id','name']);
        return view('dojo.show', compact(['dojo','fighter','master']));
    }
```

- `dojo.blade.php`

```
@can('showAdmin')
    <a href="{{ url("show-dojo/$d->id") }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;Show</a>
@endcan
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to put the model :

```
@can('showAdmin', \App\Model\User::class)
```

or

```
@can('showAdmin', auth()->user())
```

also make sure to register the policy in `AuthServiceProvider.php` put it inside the `protected $policies` which is acccept the `Model` as a key and the `Policy` as its value

```
protected $policies = [
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
]
```

[Authorization in Blade file](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#via-blade-templates)

[Registering the policies](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#registering-policies)

Comment: Thnaks for your help.